# Does this code violate One Definition Rule?

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

Some code in AOSP10 seems to violate ODR:

source 1:

```
struct ExtentsParam
{
  void init (const OT::cff1::accelerator_t *_cff)
  {
    path_open = false;
    cff = _cff;
    bounds.init ();
  }
  void start_path ()         { path_open = true; }
  void end_path ()           { path_open = false; }
  bool is_path_open () const { return path_open; }
  bool    path_open;
  Bounds  bounds;
  const OT::cff1::accelerator_t *cff;
};
```

from:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/harfbuzz_ng/+/refs/heads/android10-gsi/src/hb-ot-cff1-table.cc

source 2:

```
struct ExtentsParam
{
  void init ()
  {
    path_open = false;
    min_x.set_int (0x7FFFFFFF);
    min_y.set_int (0x7FFFFFFF);
    max_x.set_int (-0x80000000);
    max_y.set_int (-0x80000000);
  }
  void start_path ()         { path_open = true; }
  void end_path ()           { path_open = false; }
  bool is_path_open () const { return path_open; }
  void update_bounds (const Point &pt)
  {
    if (pt.x < min_x) min_x = pt.x;
    if (pt.x > max_x) max_x = pt.x;
    if (pt.y < min_y) min_y = pt.y;
    if (pt.y > max_y) max_y = pt.y;
  }
  bool  path_open;
  Number min_x;
  Number min_y;
  Number max_x;
  Number max_y;
};
```

from:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/harfbuzz_ng/+/refs/heads/android10-gsi/src/hb-ot-cff2-table.cc

build script:

```
...
srcs: [
    ...
    "src/hb-ot-cff1-table.cc",
    "src/hb-ot-cff2-table.cc",
],
...
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/harfbuzz_ng/+/refs/heads/android10-gsi/Android.bp

These too sourses are built into the same shared library. Both sources have the definition of "struct ExtentsParam" and the content are absolutely different. Both struct seems to be used only locally.

The two source have similiar names so the chance of unintentinal name duplication is low. And the chance of ODR violation in Google could be low.

Does it?

Comment: Type the code in the question instead of providing references.

Comment: With ODR, as with other ill formed program NDR, (and also UB), things can "works as expected". So bug can be unnoticed easily in those cases.

Comment: @Jarod42 is it possible it doesn't violate ODR? If ODR can exists somewhare in Google's code, then why doesn't the build systems begain to check these potential patterns a long time ago which doesn't consume so much time?

Comment: From the partial information you have provided, it's not possible to be certain.  Assuming both source files are compiled and linked into the same program, and that the `struct ExtentsParam` are in the same scope (e.g. in the same namespace) then the behaviour is undefined since the `struct` definitions do not consist of the same set of tokens.    If there are differences from that (e.g. the two `struct` definitions are in different namespaces), then the behaviour may be well-defined.

Comment: @jw_ That's a good question. I'd expect a static analyzer to catch this to be honest.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings If this still happen now, then it should have been keeping happening for decades, then how can it be possible that that static analyzer is a standard everywhere?

Comment: @jw_ It isn't ;)

Comment: _"the chance of ODR violation in Google could be low."_ For what it's worth, this seems like an undefended appeal to authority. Google devs aren't gods.

Comment: *"to check these potential patterns a long time ago which doesn't consume so much time?"* With C-Preprocessor, template, there are already lot of allowed duplicated. So the assumption that it doesn't comsume so much time is IMO optimistic.With C++20 modules, thing might be improved in that regards.

Comment: @Jarod42 The check happen only on the preprocessed code. Why template imply duplication? - different instance have different signature. It's inline that cause normal duplication. The tool only need to assert one thing - code with the same name come from the same position of the same source file - like a header file which cover most inline duplications. For this question, the two code come from different source file - just report this ant let the author rename one seem to be enough.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Even god make mistake, only tool and flow can prevent such trivial mistake - I mean doesn't Google have such tool/flow applied?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes template indeed imply duplication but that dup is like inline - come from the same template from the same position of the same source which is considered normal by the checker.

Comment: @jw_ Looks like not!

Comment: @jw_: Even #include order might introduce ODR violations with not the same set of overloads visible. I didn't say some ODR violations are not detectable, but it is more complicated than you think IMO. even your *"the two code come from different source file"* also requires to check that the definitions differ.

Comment: @Jarod42 The goal of most tool is to use miminum cost to cover the most common problem - "same name from differenct position" can cover quite a few cases but even this feature is missing. "requires to check that the definitions differ" The only thing to do for this is pre-processing all the translation unit in the library and trace and assert the uniqueness of <name,position,file> where name is a name for a non C++ function def or a name of a struct/class def - you don't need to dive in to the struct/class.

Comment: @Jarod42 For example, some one like to write the same def into different places which doesn't violate ODR but still get caught by this check - let you put the duplication into a single file - or one place may get edited in the future and violate ODR. This is a check stricter than ODR in most cased - or even every case but no proof for now.

Comment: Uniqueness of files is already not trivial with links. definition is missing as, you might have manually duplicated the (inline) definition, and it would be correct (but indeed warning might be justifiable for future proof). *"pre-processing all the translation"* Result of pre-processing creates really huge file. And you have in addition to remember origin of each "text" (complicated even more with MACRO/#include).

Comment: From practical point of view, build system works by TU, transforms it to be used by linker. So linker could detect some ODR violations, but it doesn't work with original TUs anymore.

Comment: @Jarod42 File link can be dealed with, decl is not scaned as described - only def (may have problem but will be niche). You only run this check sometimes, not everytime you edit the code, performance doesn't matter at all. If this discussion continues, the final solution is here...

Comment: @Jarod42 This checker have to be run out of the built system, on all the sources. Now I really think this stricter-than-ODR checker is very real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**: as these are both in the global namespace, this absolutely violates the ODR.

There is no exemption for class types used only within the translation unit in which they're defined; a program may only contain *one* class type with any given name.

It falls at the very first requirement for meeting criteria for exemption from this rule:

> There can be more than one definition of a *[..]* class type *[..]* 
>   in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. *[..]* Given such an entity named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, all of the following requirements shall be satisfied. *[..]* Each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens [..] ([ref](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12))

The developers are just "getting lucky" that the linker didn't try to do any antics that result in symptoms for this violation.

This is what namespaces are for. For example, if the class type is only used within the translation unit in which it's defined, it could have been defined inside an anonymous namespace.